# JQuery Datepicker to PHP variable without form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I'm having a situation and I've got the feeling it's quite simple to fix, but I can't seem to find the right keywords / way to do it.

**What I've got**

A JQuery Datepicker without a form. It's attached to a span, because I want my calendar to be a menu-item on my website. If I hover/click The 'Calendar' menu-item, the Datepicker shows:

```
<ul class="menu vertical">
  <li>
    <span id="datepicker"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**What I want / need**

I would like to pass the date selected with the datepicker to PHP, so I can use it as a variable elsewhere on the website.

I believe, from other cases, it should be possible with Ajax. But all the examples I find include an input field and/or a submit button. I don't have a form, because I would like to show the datepicker only from the menu.

What would be the best way I can do this?

**-- Edit --**

Maybe I should give a bit more explanation. I've got images, saved in dd-mm-yy folders. I would like to be able to select a date with the datepicker and then show the images from that folder in a gallery. This is the code for the gallery:

```
<?php
$date = INPUT FROM DATEPICKER HERE;
$dirname = "images/$date/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
echo '<div id="slider" class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">';
foreach($images as $image) {
    $titel = basename("$image", ".jpg").PHP_EOL;
    echo '<li><img src="'.$image.'" alt="'.basename("$image", ".jpg").PHP_EOL.'"><p class="flex-caption">'.str_replace("_", " ", $titel).'</p></li>';
};
echo '</ul></div>';
?>
```

Comment: Use the examples you've seen using AJAX and forms, except use jQuery datepicker's `onSelect` instead of running the AJAX on a form submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript **UPDATED**:

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
    onSelect: function() {
        var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker("getDate");
        $.ajax({
            url: "processdate.php",
            type: "POST",
            async: true,
            data: {
                selected_date: date
            },
            success: function(resp) {
                if (resp === "true") {
                    alert("it worked");
                } else {
                    alert("nope :-(");
                }
            } 
        });
    }
}).datepicker("setDate", new Date());//Set current date.
```

**JAVASCRIPT NOTE**

This will set the date to the current date, for display purposes only, but it will not run the AJAX call because if it did your users would be instantly redirected.  Personally I recommend adding a button next to the datepicker that goes to the next page instead of automatically redirecting on select.

processdate.php, create this php file in same directory as page that has the js

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST["selected_date"])){
    $_SESSION["date"] = $_POST["selected_date"];
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
?>
```

your php, this is the page you should redirect to after you have the AJAX working.

```
<?php
session_start();
$date = $_SESSION["date"];
$dirname = "images/$date/";
$images = glob($dirname."*.jpg");
echo '<div id="slider" class="flexslider"><ul class="slides">';
foreach($images as $image) {
    $titel = basename("$image", ".jpg").PHP_EOL;
    echo '<li><img src="'.$image.'" alt="'.basename("$image", ".jpg").PHP_EOL.'"><p class="flex-caption">'.str_replace("_", " ", $titel).'</p></li>';
};
echo '</ul></div>';
?>
```

Once you have this working replace `alert("it worked");` with whatever you want to happen if it's successful, I'm presuming a redirect to your image page.

Comment: tested and it should work, better if `var date = $(this).html();` replace with `var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker("getDate");`

Comment: I added your code to my page and created processdate.php with 'echo $_POST['selected_date'];' in it, but if I select a date I get 'nope :-('. What's going wrong?

Comment: @ZipperZapper The success code is checking that the response consists only of the word 'true'. So when you echo out the received date, it causes the function to print out "nope :-(".

Comment: @Gareth I'm sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

I edited my original question with some additional information, maybe it helps.

Comment: I got this answer confused with another similar one I had, edited again.

Comment: @WheatBeak Thank you so much for helping out, the first part is working now, I get 'It worked'. So I changed that into a redirect to test.php, where I added the code to generate the gallery with $_SESSION as you show in your example. That part doesn't seem to work yet, I get: "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$date' (T_VARIABLE) in test.php on line 3"

Comment: Sorry about that, I forgot the semicolon at the end of `session_start();` add that and you should be good.

Comment: @WheatBeak Wow, quite stupid I didn't see that myself. Working like a charm now! Thank you very much.

Comment: @WheatBeak Just a quick additional question: can I pass a default day, today, to PHP before somebody picks a day? So when the page loads?

Comment: @ZipperZapper, yes you can, concept will be to set `var date` as global variable then `var date = new Date();var today = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate());` and ajax method then should be DOM ready so when page load ajax method call execute  (one ajax call DOM ready and other Ajax call when date change) also make respective changes in `onSelect: function()`, OP can update the answer with respective changes

Comment: No need to do all that, you can simply add `.datepicker("setDate", new Date());` to the end of the first datepicker, I've updated my answer.  Be sure to read my notes as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a post, it is shorthand ajax for the post method.

```
$.post('path/to/php', {variable_name: $('#datepicker')}, function(return_data, result, xhr){
    if(result == 'success')
        console.log(return_data); //or do whatever you want, or keep it empty
});
```

You can then receive this variable again in your php like you would a normal post like so:

```
$_POST['variable_name']
```