# JQuery Datepicker getDate format and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I'm using a datepicker to select a date and pass that date to PHP to show images from a certain date ([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35877903/jquery-datepicker-to-php-variable-without-form/)). Strange enough, this works fine in Firefox, but not in Chrome, Internet Explorer, Edge and Opera.

Javascript on Datepicker-page

```
$("#datepicker").datepicker({
onSelect: function() {
    var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker("getDate");
    $.ajax({
        url: "processdate.php",
        type: "POST",
        async: true,
        data: {
            selected_date: date
        },
        success: function(resp) {
            if (resp === "true") {
                window.location.href = "test.php";
            } else {
                alert("nope :-(");
            }
        } 
    });
};
```

That is passed to `processdate.php`, from where I use it further:

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
 session_start();
}
if(isset($_POST["selected_date"])){
    $_SESSION["date"] = $_POST["selected_date"];
    echo "true";
} else {
    echo "false";
}
?>
```

I created `test.php` to echo the data and see why it was failing:

```
<?php
    if(!isset($_SESSION)){
        session_start();
    }
    $datePicker = $_SESSION["date"];

    $datePHP = strtotime($datePicker);
    $date = date('d-m-Y', $datePHP );

    echo $datePicker;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $datePHP;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $date;
?>
```

**Output Test.php in Firefox, working and how it should be:**

> Wed Mar 02 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100
>   1456873200
>   02-03-2016

**Output Test.php in Chrome, not working, second row (strtotime) missing**

> Wed Mar 02 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (West-Europa (standaardtijd))
>
> 01-01-1970

As you can see, Chrome does not seem to echo `strtotime`. Same goes voor IE/Edge/Opera. It puzzles me how that's possible? I tried setting the getDate format, but that didn't seem to work?

Comment: Remove the @ suppressing any errors that might be occuring.

Comment: I did, no errors. For some reason it looks like Chrome does nothing with `strtotime`

Comment: Chrome is not doing anything with strtotime(), strtotime() is a php function and is executed on the server.

Comment: @NeilMasters I know, but in Firefox it generates something and in Chrome it doesn't. So how can that be explained? The POST is working, because the first line, the date, is right. The second line isn't showing in Chrome, with a failing third row (01-01-1970) as a result. It puzzles me why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same problem on both Chrome and Firefox.  The PHP strtotime() function doesn't recognize the date/time string because it contains time zone information.  It works if you clip this information off like as follows (you will have to adjust manually for timezone):

```
<?php
if(!isset($_SESSION)){
    session_start();
}
$datePicker = $_SESSION["date"];
// Remove time zone information from the string so that it can be parsed
$index=strpos($datePicker,"GMT");
$datePicker=substr($datePicker,0,$index-1);
$datePHP = strtotime($datePicker);
$date = date('d-m-Y', $datePHP );

echo $datePicker;
echo "<br>";
echo $datePHP;
echo "<br>";
echo $date;
?>
```

Comment: Wow, you're right! In my case Chrome adds: "(West-Europa (standaardtijd))" (Dutch) after that. I didn't even take notice of that part, but if I remove that piece, it works! Weird. There should be a way to get cleaner data out of the datepicker in the first place I would say, but how.

Comment: Jeah, tried that one in a few different ways, but had no result.

Comment: Got it, add "date = $.datepicker.formatDate("dd-mm-yy", date);" in your onSelect after the "getDate" line

Comment: You're right, that seems to work! I tried before without `date =` in front of it. Nice, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing a:

```
console.log(date);
```

on your date variable and checking in the console just to make sure that it is actually getting a date through on each browser. The issue is most likely to be on your javascript as, like someone has already pointed out, the php is executed on the server so it would either work or fail on every browser, not be selective.

Comment: Where should I put that? Looking at the first row of output from both browsers, I would say the date is getting trough on all browsers. That rule is the correct date I picked from the datepicker and changes if I pick another date. I tried formatting that rule in the first place in the javascript, but I can't seem to make that work either?

Comment: Go straight after `var date = $('#datepicker').datepicker("getDate");` I'd also add a `console.log(resp)` to your success function too. That will make things a lot easier to debug